# Excluir trecho de uma string com replaceAll

Tags: java, regex

Tenho uma string, exemplo:

```
&texto-outroTexto=09213sdadwqWDQS
```

Onde `"09213sdadwqWDQS"` seria qualquer texto e `"&texto-outroTexto="` seria um texto fixo.

Eu queria fazer o Regex dessa string. Fiz dessa maneira, mas não funcionou:

```
texto.replaceAll("&texto-outroTexto=[A-Za-z0-9]","");
```

Como eu faria?

Comment: "não funcionou" é meio vago. Você quer remover qual trecho? A primeira parte (o texto fixo) ou a segunda (o "qualquer texto")? Qual deve ser a string final?

Comment: Queria remover o trecho todo

Comment: &texto-outroTexto=09213sdadwqWDQS eu queria remover este trecho todo do resto da String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Você quase acertou.*

Para remover o trecho todo, você deve usar uma regex que tem a parte fixa, seguida da parte "qualquer texto", mas usando um [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), como `*` ou `+`:

```
String s = texto.replaceAll("&texto-outroTexto=[A-Za-z0-9]*", "");
```

Repare no `*`. Ele significa "zero ou mais repetições" do que quer que tenha antes. Como o que vem antes é `[A-Za-z0-9]` (letras ou números), isso quer dizer que você quer zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer um destes caracteres.

Sem o `*`, a regex substitiu apenas uma ocorrência do caractere. E não se esqueça de atribuir o resultado de `replaceAll` em uma variável, pois este método retorna outra `String` (a `String` original não é alterada).

Você também pode mudar o quantificador para `+` (uma ou mais ocorrências), vai depender dos seus casos de uso.

Ou, se você sabe a quantidade de caracteres, pode usar também `{}`, de 3 maneiras diferentes:

- `[A-Za-z0-9]{2,8}`: no mínimo 2, no máximo 8 caracteres
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}`: no mínimo 2 caracteres, sem limite máximo
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{8}`: exatamente 8 caracteres

Use o que se encaixar melhor para o seu caso.

Para mais detalhes sobre os quantificadores, veja [este tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html).

Comment: HAHA! Muito Obrigado, hkotsubo! Deu certo!